# Theorem about topology inducing almost everywhere convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Can somebody explain this theorem to me? It's in the book *Achim Klenke: »Probability Theory — A Comprehensive Course«.*

[image: Corollary 6.14 Achim Klenke: Probability Theory]

I don't even know what *"a topology that induces almost everywhere convergence"* means. And isn't convergence almost everywhere / in measure just defined for ***random variables?*** How can it be defined for the whole space?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know what a topology is?  In any topology you have a notion of convergence.

Comment: A random variable is just a measurable function, and the space on which we are considering a topology on is the space of measurable functions.  This answers your second question.